# Get the list of SharePoint Pages with Page layouts using power shell

Tags: shell, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get the list of all pages in my site collections with in all webs. 
The power shell doesn't return anything.
Here is my power shell code . Any guidance please.

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added

    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
  Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
  }

    $str = "http://example.com/" 


     function ProcessSubWebs($str)
       {
     if([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($currentWeb))
   {            
    $publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($currentWeb)
    $publishingPages = $publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()
    foreach ($publishingPage in $publishingPages)
    {
        if($publishingPage.ListItem['Title'] -ne $null)
        {
           select Uri, Title, @{Name=’PageLayout’;Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}} 
        }
    }

    foreach($sub in $currentWeb.Webs)
    {
        if($sub.Webs.Count -gt 0)
        {
            ProcessSubWebs($sub)    
        }
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "FINISHED"
}
else
{
    Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Red "^ not a publishing site" 
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made several changes including calling the function. Please compare my code to yours and let me know if you have any questions. This works in my environment.

```
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1)  {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-location $home

$str = "http://example.com/"
function ProcessSubWebs($str)
{
    $currentWeb = Get-SPWeb $str
    if([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($currentWeb))
    {
        $publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($currentWeb)
        $publishingPages = $publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()
        foreach ($publishingPage in $publishingPages)
        {
            if($publishingPage.ListItem['Title'] -ne $null)
            {
                select Uri, Title, @{Name=’PageLayout’;Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}}
                $publishingPage | select Uri, Title, @{Name=’PageLayout’;Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}}
            }
        }
        foreach($sub in $currentWeb.Webs)
        {
            if($sub.Webs.Count -gt 0)
            {
                ProcessSubWebs($sub.Url)
            }
        }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "FINISHED"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Red "$str not a publishing site"
    }
}

ProcessSubWebs($str)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works i changed the output format to table